# How to set up a Raspberry Pi to act as a printer and save printed files?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I need to set up a Raspberry Pi as a printer. When something is printed to the Raspberry it should save the file, so that I can work with it.
The plan is, to use it instead of the printer to save paper.

EDIT:
It will be printed from a cash register - it should replace the printer. And I want to read the file with an application to save the informations into my database.

Comment: Print from Windows?

Comment: Where would the files be saved?

Comment: Your best bet is to emulate a Postscript printer and save the files as EPS or a PDF printer and save the files as PDF. Other printer protocols don't have convenient desktop software to open them. For example there is no desktop software I know of that can open PCL or XPS data